# How to sort Dictionary on keys in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, dictionary

I have a Dictionary that I want to sort by its keys.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>(){
    {1, "a"},
    {3, "c"},
    {2, "b"}
};
```

Converting it to a `SortedDictionary` alone doesn't work because I need the keys to be **descending** in value:

```
var sortedDict = new SortedDictionary<int, string>(dict);
foreach (var k in sortedDict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(k);
}

// Result:
[1, a]
[2, b]
[3, c]

// Desired result:
[3, c]
[2, b]
[1, a]
```

Is there any way to sort the Dictionary with a custom sorting option (like a lambda)?

Comment: SortedDictionary  has a constructor where you can pass in an IComparer<T> which should allow you to sort as you like.

Comment: `foreach (var kvp in dict.OrderByDescending(e => e.Key))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>(){
  {1, "a"},
  {3, "c"},
  {2, "b"}
};

foreach (var k in dict.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key))
{
   Console.WriteLine(k);
}
```

Comment: Yes but how do I convert a `System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int, string>>` back to a `Dictionary`?

Comment: You cannot without loss of sorting. A Dictionary is not sorted.